# Make a new console window via CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'am trying to create a new console window using `CreateProcess`. But when I start the program I only see the default console window.

How can I show the new console window and print some text there?

```
HANDLE  m_hPipe = 0;

m_hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    L"name",                
    PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,   
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |     
    PIPE_READMODE_BYTE |    
    PIPE_WAIT,              
    1,                      
    4096,                   
    0,                      
    1,                      
    NULL);                  

if (m_hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return -1;

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
GetStartupInfo(&si);
TCHAR cmd[] = L"cmd.exe";
CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

BOOL bConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(m_hPipe, NULL) ?
    TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

DWORD cbWritten;
WriteFile(m_hPipe, "some text", 10, &cbWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: `CreateProcess` does not create a console window, it creates a process. If that process happens to be a console-mode app, that process will in turn allocate a new console if it is not already started with one. What do you mean by "default console window"? If your app is a GUI-mode app, you can still allocate a console as well, using `AllocConsole`, but remember that a process can be associated with only one console at a time.

Comment: Why are you using `GetStartupInfo()`? That gets the `STARTUPINFO` of the calling process, which probably isn't suitable for the new process. Also, what is the point of creating a named pipe that nobody connects to? If you are trying to use the pipe as a way of writing text to the new process, then you need to give the pipe to `CreateProcess()` to use as the STDIN for the new process. See [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) on MSDN for more details.

Comment: A process can create a console by specifying the CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag in a call to CreateProcess. This method creates a new console that is accessible to the child process but not to the parent process. See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console